# Extract page content where there is a delay in the actual content using Playwright

Tags: javascript, playwright

I am trying to capture the privacy notice of this page - "https://www.imaginegolf.com/privacy". However, if you look at the page - it takes a while to load the privacy notice. Is there a way to make playwright wait and grab the contents of the page? I tried options like load, networkidle, commit and domcontentloaded

Sample source code

```
import {chromium}  from 'playwright'; // Web scraper Library
import * as fs from 'fs';

(async function () {
    const chromeBrowser = await chromium.launch({ headless: true }); // Chromium launch and options
    const context = await chromeBrowser.newContext({ ignoreHTTPSErrors: true ,
        userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36',
      });
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://www.imaginegolf.com/privacy", { waitUntil: 'networkidle', timeout: 60000 });
    let content = await page.content();
    fs.writeFileSync('test.html', content);
    console.log("done")
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to probably wait for an element that contains or is part of the content, basically something that indicates the content you expect is loaded. Since you’re just using Playwright Library (not Test), you can’t use `expect` to asynchronously expect it to be visible within a time frame, but you’re not trying to assert it anyways, just wait for it before moving on. So I would recommend using the [waitFor method](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-wait-for), like so:

```js
await page.getByText(‘Privacy Notice’).waitFor()
```

Or with whatever locator best makes sense. Note that waitFor defaults to waiting until it is visible, hence being able to not pass any arguments, though you can always be explicit if you want.

Comment: Thank you.. any idea why I may get this error - page.getByText not a function.

Comment: @Sunil One possibility that immediately comes to mind is a playwright version mismatch, since that function was added in 1.27 which is one of the last few. Which version are you running?

Comment: Thank you. I noticed I was in 1.25 - now changed to 1.27 . But even after changing the version, I am not able to grab the content. were you able to extract the content from your end ?

Comment: Makes sense! Hmm, no I haven’t actually tried to get it myself. I did take a quick glance on a computer at the page dom though, and noticed that it looks like you’re dealing with an iframe, which adds an extra piece. If I had the exact locators, I would add it to my answer, but basically to locate the element within the iframe, you can use [the frameLocator](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-frame-locator) to locate the iframe and then the element within.

Comment: I’m also unsure if page.content will capture iframe contents (haven’t tried/dealt with one yet), but you may have to use [`page.frame().content()`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-frame) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a check with expect and specify a timeout to verify that the privacy note is visible. So something like this maybe:

```
  await page.goto("https://www.imaginegolf.com/privacy");
  await expect(page.locator('text="PRIVACY NOTICE").toBeVisible({ timeout:5000 });
  let content = await page.content();
  fs.writeFileSync('test.html', content);
```

Just adapt the locator and timeout to your needs and continue with your workflow after the expect succeds.

Comment: Thank you Basti. I am not using test library as such but it helps in test routines